# Why does image with position: fixed only show up my computer?

Tags: html, css

On an assignment earlier, I made a mistake with the position: fixed property and didn't specify a position for an image; yet it still showed up on my PC, but didn't show up on other PC's.

The cache was cleared, both PC's had the same image file in the same directory, and had the exact same html file. What could have caused this?

html in question:

```
#logo {width: 255px; float: left; position: fixed; }

<img src="w3clogo.png" alt="image failed to load" id="logo">
```

Comment: Positioned elements will normally be displayed in the same location as when they hadn't been positioned. So if the image is the first element on the page, that would be the top left corner of the window. That said, I don't know what went wrong. Did you use the same browser on both machines?

Comment: Yes, tried same browsers (tried firefox, google chrome, and safari), and every time my PC had the image show up but the other PC didn't have the image show up.

Comment: Interesting. I guess you don't have a webpage with the problem, that someone can take a look at?

Comment: I lost points on an assignment in my web development class, because the image didn't show up on his screen, and the professor said he'll give me the points back if I can explain why it didn't show up on his screen but it showed up on mine.